# SQL Server complex query for YTD

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, sql-server-2008-r2

[image: SQL Server complex query]

How to update the KPI# values based on the month?

If the month is 4, it should calculate YTD = 1 + 2 + 3 + 4.

Comment: Please also show us what the table should look like after the update.  This is not clear to me.

Comment: This is the updated table only. before it contains null values only.

Answer (score 0):

If you have SQL Server 2012 then you can use:-

```
sum (KPI#) over (partition by whatever ORDER BY [Month]) as YTD
```

If you have 2008 r2 then you can't use an order by clause in sum windowing function and will have to use a CTE instead.